# HTML5 Notification Chrome45

Tags: html, google-chrome, notifications

HTML notification working in firefox41, but do not work in Chrome45.

```
function spawnNotification(theTitle,theBody,theIcon) {
  var options = {
      body: theBody,
      icon: theIcon
  }
  var n = new Notification(theTitle,options);
}
document.getElementById('notify').addEventListener('click', function() {
 spawnNotification('Title','Text','aike.jpg');
});
```

Comment: What is the desired behaviour that you expect to see in Chrome45?